# Intake boots for 79 GS1000

Tags: suzuki

I recently replaced the carbs on my 79 GS1000 Suzuki from 27MM to 36MM
I modified some old Kawasaki intakes to fit by elongating the 2 mounting screw holes on intakes boots. The Bike runs great! but I'm not happy with what was modified on the boot specificatly the possibility of air leaks. Does anybody know if any Suzuki intakes will fit the 36MM Mikuni carbs without elongating the mountin holes?
Thanks

Comment: Nice mod.  What model kawasaki boots did you use, just so I can have an idea of what the outcome was.  Do you have any pics you jam into the post?  AND....is the GS an S model?  Just curious.

Comment: What make/model/year did the Mikuni carbs come off of and what did you use for the current boots?

Comment: Pictures would be useful here.